How to configure Rubocop to skip counting log lines - Metrics/MethodLength AllowedPatterns/AllowedMethods
Running RuboCop results in the following error
$ rubocop
Running RuboCop...

Offenses:

C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [25/10] (https://rubystyle.guide#short-methods)
def example_method ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Where the example_method is
def example_method
  Log.debug "Debug message 1"
  Log.debug "Debug message 2"
  Log.debug "Debug message 3"
  Log.debug "Debug message 4"
  Log.debug "Debug message 5"
  Log.debug "Debug message 6"
  Log.debug "Debug message 7"
  Log.debug "Debug message 8"
  Log.debug "Debug message 9"
  Log.debug "Debug message 10"
  Log.debug "Debug message 11"
  Log.debug "Debug message 12"
  Log.debug "Debug message 13"
  Log.debug "Debug message 14"
  Log.debug "Debug message 15"
  Log.debug "Debug message 16"
  Log.debug "Debug message 17"
  Log.debug "Debug message 18"
  Log.debug "Debug message 19"
  Log.debug "Debug message 20"
  Log.debug "Debug message 21"
  Log.debug "Debug message 22"
  Log.debug "Debug message 23"
  Log.debug "Debug message 24"
  Log.debug "Debug message 25"
end

Since I want to allow Log messages, I tried to tweak RuboCop configuration as follows (after looking at ref#1, ref#2, ref#3)
# .rubocop.yml
Metrics/MethodLength:
  AllowedPatterns:
    - '^\s*Log\.(debug|info|warn|error|fatal).*'

But when executing RuboCop the error output is the same (see the beginning of the question). How could I configure RuboCop Metrics/MethodLength to allow patterns/methods to not count calls for Log?

why not just use rubocop: disable Metrics/MethodLength for specific methods?

@AntonBogdanov This is not what I want since I would like to configure RuboCop not to count Log calls in all methods.

The AllowedPatterns option on the cop matches method names that should be allowed. This is methods that should be allowed to be longer than the limit, and NOT method calls that shouldn't count towards the limit.
There is an option to count or not count comments, but nothing about other arbitrary lines.
If you think this is something that Rubocop should support, open an issue or a PR in their repo, or fork it.

I see no documentation that supports what you say and it feels like you are mixing between Metrics/MethodLength that count the number of lines in a method and other cop that also has AllowedPatterns

@Mr. According to the source code of the cop, the AllowedMethods and AllowedPatterns options are only checked against the method name. The CodeLengthCalculator has no facility to ignore lines based on patterns.

@HolgerJust Thanks. So there is no way to ignore lines with specific pattern, correct?

Correct. You can only fold some constructs into one assumed line (such as multi-line hash or array statements or method calls) or instruct comments. You can not ignore arbitrary other lines. You might be able to extend CodeLengthCalculator#irrelevant_line? though, following the advice to open an issue / PR in rubocop's repository.

As stated in the other answer AllowedPatterns is for method names so if for allowing long methods that have locks you can do 2 things:

add log at the end of such method names and use regex in AllowedPatterns to detect and allow them
use max option to increase the number of lines allowed

That's not the exact solution but it is something that can solve your problem
